# Why BroadcastReceiver not change global variable in Application

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, global-variables

I need global variable in my application. Variable will be set and periodically change in BroadcastReceiver. And I get and use it in the Thread in the Service. My code:

I create Application Class for globals variables:

```
    package com.bklah.blah;
    import android.app.Application;
    public class ApplicationBlah extends Application
     {
       public boolean eSettings;
       public boolean getSettings()
        {
          return this.eSettings;
        }
       public void setSettings( boolean eSettings)
        {
          this.eSettings = eSettings;
        }
     }
```

I decrale it in AndroidManifest file:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/sAppName"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                 android:name=".ApplicationBlah">
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastBlah"
              android:process=":remote" />
```

I periodically change variable in cicle through BroadcastReceiver:

```
     public class BroadcastBlah extends BroadcastReceiver
      {
        @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent) 
         {
           ((ApplicationBlah)context.getApplicationContext()).setSettings( true);
           // or ...
           // ((ApplicationBlah)getApplication()).setSettings(true); 
         }
      }
```

And I try use variable in cicle in Thread in Service:

```
    public class ServiceBlah extends Service
     {
       public static Thread threadBlah = null;
       public String fUse( Context context)
        {
          boolean eSeetingsCurrent1 =((ApplicationBlah)context.getApplicationContext()).eSettings;
          boolean eSeetingsCurrent2 = ApplicationBlah.eSettings;
          boolean eSeetingsCurrent3 = ((ApplicationBlah)context.getApplicationContext()).getSettings();
          // --- all this variables always == false, but i need true from Receiver
        }

       public void fThreadBlah( final Context context)
        {
          final Handler handler = new Handler()
           {
             @Override
             public void handleMessage( Message message) { ... }
           };

          threadBlah = new Thread()
           {
             @Override
             public void run()
              {
                final Message message = handler.obtainMessage( 1, fUse( context));
                handler.sendMessage( message);
              }
           };
          threadBlah.setPriority( Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
          threadBlah.start();
        }
     }
```

But I always get false in global variable. Please say what is my error?

Comment: Is your onReceive even called?

Comment: @Ascorbin, yes, onReceive called on its events (I delete log-function in onReceive for clearable code)

Comment: Not really sure but is it possible that you have to make eSettings as a static variable? or make a singleton of ApplicationBlah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find solution: I delete `android:process=":remote"` from receiver's attributes in Manifest. It work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Youre using a contect to get a context then cast it to Application, it looks strange. Try his, I don't know if it'll work though.

```
((ApplicationBlah)getApplication()).setSettings(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just primitive data type that you are after, I think you can use SharedPreferences, it is really easy to use. On your activity:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("eSeetingsCurrent1", eSeetingsCurrent1);
```

You can then get this anywhere in your application with:

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 boolean eSeetingsCurrent1 = settings.getBoolean("eSeetingsCurrent1", false);
```

More info @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: thanks, this is not my way :) BroadcastReciever will change this variable very often, and I know SharedPreference used save to file and it will frozen the system.

Comment: in that case then have you try putting 'static' keyword to your eSettings or even make ApplicationBlah static?